# How many graphics I need to create for all iOS devices background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background-image

How many graphics I need to create for all iOS devices background?

let me explain:I'm not talking about the launchscreen. but an image that i want to use to color the background of view controllers. for example: for a button, a navigation controller or else i need create only three graphics e.g. 25x25, 50x50 and 75x75.

but for background of view controller?

iPhone 4s, 5, 5s, 6/6s and 6/6s plus has different sizes. I need to create one graphic for each size and in the code detect the device and set up the backgroundImage of ViewController?

Comment: Are you talking about creating a UIColor from a pattern with the method `colorWithPatternImage`?

Answer (score 1):

Only 2x for  and 3x (50x50 and 75x75).
[More information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a unique background image for every resolution (there's overlap between some devices), or you can create one file that that works for the largest resolution and then center it on all devices. Whether the second approach works really depends on the image content, since there's difference in aspect ratio between some of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough, if you make one for the 4s and one for the newer Devices (all have the same aspect ratio)
I would recommend you to make the 4s @2x and the other @2x and @3x

Answer (score 0):

then if you should give me a number of graphics, how many are they? 4?

1 for iPhone 4s and early,
1 for iPhone 5/5s,
1 for iPhone 6/6s,
1 for iPhone 6+/6s+,

right?

Comment: I know that if the background is full color or pattern background, you can set in asset your image like pattern. and it fits to size. but if you have an image, like a photo?